# waitsStats_Deltas View

Tags: sp-blitzfirst

This is a question related with Brent Ozar's FirstResponder Kit. How to interpret column "wait_time_minutes_per_minute" on the WaitStats_delta view?

Regards,

Enrique

Comment: For people who don't know what it is, you need to explain it here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In a one-minute time span on the clock - like from 9:00 AM to 9:01 AM - this column shows how many minutes of time the SQL Server spent waiting.

For example, if 4 single-threaded queries were blocked the whole time, you might see 4 minutes of LCK% waits in 1 minute on the clock.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, is clear for me now. Excelent work on the FirstRespoderKit.